# Dynamic findViewById inside custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I'm working on a library called [Waterfall Toolbar](https://github.com/HugoCastelani/waterfall-toolbar). It's a view that listens to a `RecyclerView` which is given by the user through java, but I want to add the possibility to refer through XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.hugocastelani.waterfalltoolbar.sample.SampleActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.hugocastelani.waterfalltoolbar.library.WaterfallToolbar
        android:id="@+id/waterfall_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:recycler_view="@id/recycler_view">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

    </com.hugocastelani.waterfalltoolbar.library.WaterfallToolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm able to get `RecyclerView`'s ID inside my custom view class, but since I can't use `findViewById` to find it without its parent layout, I would have to inflate parent, but I can't as well because its layout ID is unknown by me, since each user will give the name he want.

In short, I need a way to findViewById inside a custom view without inflating parent. I know it's possible because some Android's layouts, e.g. RelativeLayout, do it all the time. Does anyone know how?

Edit:
Let me materialize my thoughts. Code below is what I would have to do to get target `RecyclerView`:

```
public class WaterfallToolbar extends CardView {
    ...        

    private void init() {
        final Integer recyclerViewID = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.WaterfallToolbar_recycler_view, 0);
        // findViewById(recyclerViewID) returns null, so I gotta use the code below
        // parent_layout holds both custom view and recyclerview 
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.parent_layout, this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(recyclerView);
    }

    ...
}
```

But as I said, `parent_layout` is unknown.

Comment: when user will inflate a layout , wont you inflate the custom view ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the layout he inflated, so I can't refer it.